# How do I make proofs with long formulae more readable without sacrificing clarity?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, notation, propositional-calculus

##### Question

A lot of things I'm trying to prove just now are turning into "notational hell", which I think makes them very hard to read. I've tried to cut down on this by assuming my reader will understand what definitions are in play, modularising my proofs and skipping explanation of steps that I hope are obvious. I've also tried relabeling formulae with short names (i.e., $\def\val#1{V_\pli(#1)}\def\p{\phi}\def\q{\psi}\def\s{\vDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\def\ns{\nvDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\def\pli{\mathscr{I}}\def\aa{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q}\def\ab{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\ns\q}\def\ba{\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}\def\bb{\ns\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots)):=\,\s Q),$ but for proofs of any length it seems to be more confusing than helpful. **How do I make proofs more readable without sacrificing clarity?**

---

##### Example Proof

Let $\p$ and $\q$ be wffs and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (please note that $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$). We want to show $\def\p{\phi}\def\q{\psi}\def\s{\vDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\def\ns{\nvDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q$ iff $\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))$.

> In (L1) I prove both directions of the biconditional, which I don't think I need to do because we're dealing with "=" - is this correct? I also think that (L1) is so basic that "by inspection" is appropriate - is that fair?

###### Lemma 1 (L1)

We want to show by induction that for some PL-interpretation, $\pli,$ $\val{\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}=0$ iff $\val{\p_n}=\val{\p_{n-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$.

*Base Case*

- If $\val{\p\to\q}=0$ then, by definition, $\val{\p}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$. If $\val{\p}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$, then, by definition, $\val{\p\to\q}=0$

*Induction Hypothesis (IH)*

- Assume for some arbitrary $k\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\val{p_k\to(\p_{k-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}=0$ and $\val{\p_k}=\val{\p_{k-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$

*Induction Step*

- If $\val{\p_{k+1}\to(p_k\to(\p_{k-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots)))}=0,$ then, as we know $\val{p_k\to(\p_{k-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}=0$ from the (IH), $\val{\p_{k+1}}=1$. From the (IH) $\val{\p_k}=\val{\p_{k-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$, thus $\val{\p_{k+1}}=\val{\p_k}=\val{\p_{k-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$
- Let $\val{\p_{k+1}}=1$. From the (IH) $\val{\p_k}=\val{\p_{k-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1,$ $\val{\q}=0,$ and $\val{p_k\to(\p_{k-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}=0,$ thus $\val{\p_{k+1}\to(p_k\to(\p_{k-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots)))}=0$

###### Proof of First Direction (P1)

1. For reductio, suppose it is not the case that $\aa\implies\ba$
2. It follows from (1) that there exists an $\def\pli{\mathscr{I}}\pli$ such that $\def\aa{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q}\def\ab{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\ns\q}\def\ba{\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}\def\bb{\ns\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}\aa$ and $\bb$
3. It follows from (2) that $\def\val#1{V_\pli(#1)}\val{\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}=0$
4. From (L1), the valuation on (3) can only occur when $\val{\p_n}=\val{\p_{n-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$
5. It follows from (4) that $\ab$, which contradicts (2) and proves our first direction

###### Proof of Second Direction (P2)

1. For reductio, suppose it's not the case that $\ba\implies\aa$
2. It follows from (1) that there exists an $\pli$ such that $\ba\text{ and }\ab$
3. From (2) we have $\ab$, thus, $\val{\p_n}=\val{\p_{n-1}}=\cdots=\val{\p_1}=1$ and $\val{\q}=0$
4. It follows from (3) and (L1) that $\bb\text{,}$ which contradicts (2) and proves our second direction

(P1) and (P2) prove both directions of the biconditional, hence $\def\p{\phi}\def\q{\psi}\def\s{\vDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\def\ns{\nvDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q$ iff $\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))\,\square.$

Comment: Why would you not need to prove both directions of a biconditional? Any why do you want/expect the proof to be short?

Comment: @Elliot G, for equality "x=y and y=x" so prove "x=y" and we get "y=x" for free, proving both directions - at least we would if this was a PL proof and I could be sure I could treat "=" as a relation. Also, length of proof isn't the issue, it's the notation making it hard to read that's the issue :(

Comment: whether or not something is 'obvious enough' to not require proof depends on target audience / readership. This is a judgment call that you must make. Calling too many results obvious can really dissuade weaker readers of your text, so be careful with how your tone comes across to the reader. Additionally, if you are working with a lot of logical formulae - have you considered introducing a deduction system?

Comment: The bit that puzzles me is "In (L1) I prove both directions of the biconditional, which I don't think I need to do because we're dealing with "$=$". I cannot see any $=$ anywhere.

Comment: @user2628206, that's a good point "obvious enough". As for the second part, the proofs I'm currently doing are mainly meta-logic and semantic, so I'd need to prove the deduction system and, since it would be novel(ish), I run the risk of making things more confusing. I did think about extending truth tables, though 

Comment: @ancient mathematician, the "=" comes from the valuation function. $V(P\to Q)=1$ iff $V(P)=0$ or $V(Q)=1$. I've indicated this with "by definition" in the base case. Clearly, my assumption about what is obvious isn't correct 

Comment: OK, I see. But the two things you have to show equivalent are different so the symmetry of $=$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd also be puzzled by your use of $:=$. It seems to me that you want to use $Q$ as shorthand for the long nested implication. I thought that would be done by $Q:=\dots$ and not $\dots:=Q$. And I do think  that $Q$ should be $Q_n$.

Comment: Thanks for including your long, detailed example in your question. Without that, I couldn't have written a detailed and specific answer.

Comment: @ancient mathematician, it should have been "Q:=..." that was a brain fart . I suppose my thinking is because there is only 1 way for a conditional to be false, $[V(P\to Q)=0]=[V(P)=1\land V(Q)=0]$, demonstrating that both $V(P\to Q)=0$ leads to the desired conjunction, and the desired conjunction leads to $V(P\to Q)=0$ seems redundant. If there were multiple options, then sure. Regardless, if it doesn't work, then it doesn't work. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Sometimes using an intermediate variable can help.  Not sure if it applies to this situation.

Comment: "I've tried to cut down on this by **assuming my reader will understand what definitions are in play**, modularising my proofs and **skipping explanation of steps that I hope are obvious.**" Please don't do this. As a grad student, this is what I absolutely despise. If you are new to a field, you don't know what definitions are in play and it takes forever to hunt them down. Also, unless super obvious, write down, what's going on. It saves the reader from thinking 10minutes about a step, that might turn out to be obvious. A good paper is easily accessible, not cryptic beyond any means.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Main suggestion

Instead of

> We want to show $\def\p{\phi}\def\q{\psi}\def\s{\vDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\def\ns{\nvDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q$ iff $\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))$

try it like this:

> We want to show that $$\def\p{\phi}\def\q{\psi}\def\s{\vDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\def\ns{\nvDash_{\tiny\text{PL}}}\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q \tag{1}$$ if and only if
> $$\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots)).\tag{2}$$

After that, instead of repeating the long formulas every time, just call them $(1)$ and $(2)$:

> For reductio, suppose it's not the case that $(2)\implies (1)$.  Then there must exist an $\mathscr I$ such that $(2)$ holds but $(1)$ does not.

### Lesser suggestions

1. Abbreviate $$\phi_n\to(\phi_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\phi_1\to\q)\cdots))$$ as $$\Phi_n.$$  (Don't use $Q$.  Why would you use $Q$?)

   Instead of $$V_\mathscr{I}({p_k\to(\p_{k-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))})=0$$ you can now write $$V_\mathscr{I}({p_k\to\Phi_{k-1}})=0$$ and the reader won't miss that the first variable is a  $p$ and not a $\phi$.

   You said abbreviating seems “more confusing than helpful”.  It's not.
2. Abbreviate $\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n$ as $\vec\phi$.
3. Abbreviate $$V_\mathscr{I}(\phi_n)=V_\mathscr{I}(\phi_{n-1})=\cdots=V_\mathscr{I}(\phi_1)=1$$ as $$V_\mathscr{I}(\phi_i) = 1\quad (i=1\ldots n)$$ or perhaps $$V_\mathscr{I}(\phi_{1\ldots n}) = 1.$$
4. You're abbreviating the wrong things.  You don't need to abbreviate “if and only if” as “iff”, or “Lemma 1” as “L1”. The goal here is not to remove all the normal English from your proof.  These abbreviations are more confusing than helpful.

Don't make the reader compare two long formulas to make sure they are the same, or to wonder why they are not.  Design your notation to highlight the *differences* between similar formulas.

Notation, like language, is flexible. There are no rules; you are allowed to make things up.  $\vec\phi$ is not really a vector.  It doesn't matter. You can explain it briefly: “We will abbreviate $\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n$ as $\vec\phi$.”  Nobody will be confused or forget what it means.  My suggestion $V_\mathscr{I}(\phi_{1\ldots n})$ is not standard.  It doesn't matter; the meaning is clear.

### Orthogonal suggestions

1. You're not using TeX correctly.  You don't need to keep repeating `\def`s.  Once you `\def` a new control sequence, the definition remains in force until the end of the group, or the document.  Define the important macros once, at the beginning of the file, or in an `\include`d file.
2. Define better macros.  The structure of the macros should follow the syntactic structure of your formulas.  Instead of typing out

   ```
   \def\aa{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\s\q}
   \def\ab{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n\ns\q}
   \def\ba{\s\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))}  
   \def\bb{\ns\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\q)\cdots))
   ```

   try it this way:

   ```
   \def\ps{\p_1,\,\p_2,\,\ldots,\,\p_n}
   \def\aa{\ps\s\psi}
   \def\ab{\ps\ns\psi}
   \def\pformn{\p_n\to(\p_{n-1}\to(\cdots\to(\p_1\to\psi)\cdots))}
   % now you don't need \ba or \bb, just use \s\pformn and \ns\pformn
   ```

Comment: This a brilliant answer, thank you so much for taking the time to help. I'll have a go with a rewrite. As an embarrassing aside, I was adding in "\def" as I went, but then I massively edited, which broke the formatting when I posted the question, so I did a quick copy and paste. I'm on android so I'm using stackexchange as an ide, which isn't the best

Comment: I sympathize.  My own TeX in the answer was not what I would have written had I been preparing an article with a real editor.  And thanks again for taking the time and trouble to ask a good question, without which I couldn't have written a good answer.

Comment: I would strongly suggest being very conservative or careful, or at least greatly limiting the scope of usage, when numbering formulas or equations. If you're referencing a lot of numbered formulas, this is going to take a while to decipher at the best of times. Also, when abbreviating things, I would also suggest trying to follow typical notation as closely as possible. If you're abbreviating something in a way that's counter-intuitive given typical notation, that could very well confuse readers, and standard notation reduces effort required to understand what's written.

Comment: " “We will abbreviate ϕ1,ϕ2,…,ϕn as ϕ⃗ .” Nobody will be confused or forget what it means. "  I've seen a case of this.  I particularly remember reading Lotfi Zadeh (and some people who read him) would use Leibniz's long 's' symbol, which people are familiar with from calculus texts, BUT Zadeh wasn't notating an integral, but rather a union (of fuzzy sets).  Though one author commented that it was a bad notation, it didn't seem anyone was confused by Zadeh's notation since he had explained it.

Comment: I didn't make up the $\vec\phi$ thing out of whole cloth; I've seen it used similarly elsewhere, for example in Barendregt's _Introduction to $\lambda$-Calculus_. That's how I could be so confident in declaring “Nobody will be confused.” In spite of my assertion that “you are allowed to make things up”, the only one of my suggestions that is made up is $V(\phi_{1\ldots n})=1$. I think this is a fine example of what a reasonable invention looks like. Beginning mathematicians often worry that about whether their notation is “allowed”, when the proper concern is “can it be understood?”